# array_multisort() does not modify array in first parameter

Tags: php, arguments, array-multisort

I am trying to sort `$ar1` by the descending order values of `$ar2`. Nothing is happening.

```
$ar1 = array($arperc);
$ar2 = array($arid);
array_multisort($ar1, $ar2);
print_r($ar1);
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Could you give us examples for the values of $arperc and $arid?

Comment: your arguments are the wrong way around :D

Comment: You really need to provide some example data to allow us to solve that.. But it seems that you send in an array with just one value? You probably want to just create a copy with $ar1 = $arperc; if you don't want to sort the original array.

Comment: Are these single element arrays? Are these multi-dimensional arrays? We don't know.  These is no [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the elements of `$ar2` as sorting keys, you need to change the order of arguments to `array_multisort`:

```
array_multisort($ar2, $ar1);
```

This will sort `$ar2` in ascending order, and also change the order of `$ar1` elements exactly as the order of `$ar2` is changed by the sorting. To change the order to descending:

```
array_multisort($ar2, SORT_DESC, $ar1);
```

Comment: Yes, the PHP documentation is really terrible in explaining how to use that function. I've also got that wrong. And it always worked, until it didn't. So if the first array is also being sorted, it must be an unintended side effect. https://stackoverflow.com/q/75836843/143684